# BMO2 2017 Question 4 - Bobby's Safe

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, contest-math, combinatorial-game-theory

Bobby’s booby-trapped safe requires a $3$-digit code to unlock it. Alex
has a probe which can test combinations without typing them on
the safe. The probe responds *Fail* if no individual digit is correct.
Otherwise it responds *Close*, including when all digits are correct. For
example, if the correct code is $014$, then the responses to $099$ and $014$
are both *Close*, but the response to $140$ is *Fail*. If Alex is following an optimal strategy, what is the smallest number of attempts needed to
guarantee that he knows the correct code, whatever it is?

I think the optimal number is $13$ (start by trying $000$, $111$, $\ldots$, $999$), but it's hard to find bounds here. Any help?

Comment: @quasi "The probe responds *Fail* if **no individual digit** is correct". So if at least one is correct, it responds *Close*

Comment: I would think one needs to start with "000, 001, 002..." then upon hitting "close", trying "000, 010, 020.." etc.

Comment: i think that starting with  000,111,222... is correct and needs 7 moves. But i don't think you need 6 more permutations once the 3 digits in the combination are known

Comment: This link might help (spoilers): (https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2017/01/27/bmo2-2017/), which splits each decision into two branches. I think that the problem is finding the optimal way for how early or late you should split.

Answer (score 3):

We shall first prove that the task requires at least $13$ attempts.  In the worst case scenario, Alex's first six attempts all fail, which means he has at least $(10-6)^3=64$ remaining combinations to guess.  If he gets a "Close" outcome in the seventh round, he will then have at least
$$9+9+9+3+3+3+1=37$$ possibilities for the correct code.  This means he will need at least $\left\lceil\log_2(37)\right\rceil=6$ more rounds, whence Alex cannot complete the task in fewer than $13$ trials.

We now claim that $13$ trials suffice.  For the first ten tries, Alex takes the guesses $000$, $111$, $222$, $\ldots$, $999$.

1. If he gets nine failed attempts, then the only one that gets the "Close" outcome is the correct code.
2. Suppose for the moment that Alex gets exactly two "Close" outcomes $aaa$ and $bbb$.  Then, pick a combination $ccc$ known to fail.  Test $acc$, $cac$, and $cca$ to see which digit is $a$ and which is $b$.
3. Finally, assume that Alex gets three "Close" outcomes $aaa$, $bbb$, and $ccc$.  Then, there are six possibilities left $abc$, $acb$, $bac$, $bca$, and $cab$.  Alex can guess $add$ and $bdd$, where $ddd$ is an already known failed guess.  This will establish the first digit of the combination.  Without loss of generality, the first digit is now known to be $a$.  There are only two possibilities left: $abc$ and $acb$.  Take the guess $dbc$.  If this results in a fail, then $acb$ is the correct combination; otherwise, $abc$ is the correct combination.

---

Let $M(n)$ denote the minimum number of attempts guaranteed to crack the digit code of length $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.  Then, we obviously have $M(1)=9$, $M(2)=11$, and $M(3)=13$.  Indeed, 
$$M(n) \geq \max\Big\{\big\lceil n\,\log_2(10-k)\big\rceil +k\,\Big|\,k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}\Big\}=:m(n)\,.$$
We see that $m(1)=9$, $m(2)=11$, $m(3)=12$, $m(4)= 15$, $m(5)= 18$, $m(6)= 21$, $m(7)= 24$, and for $n\geq 8$, 
$$m(n)=  \big\lceil n\,\log_2(10)\big\rceil\,.$$
I believe that the inequality $M(n)\geq m(n)$ is not sharp for all $n\geq 4$.  I struggled to find, for example, a $15$-step strategy for the case where $n=4$, and I conjecture that $$M(4)=16\,.$$

Comment: I think at the end you want the guess $dbc$; $abc$ will succeed because $a$ is correctly placed, ne?

Comment: Oh, right!  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your worst case argument as it's not clear that failing the first 6 attempts is the worst outcome. You gain a lot of information that way.

Comment: No matter which strategy use use, there is always a combination that will make you fail the first $6$ attempts and pass in the $7$-th try, given that you are using an optimal strategy.  That is, in the $7$-th try, you don't guess something you already know to fail.

Comment: @Batominovski What I mean is that just because the outcome is called "fail" that does not imply that that outcome is obviously the worst case one. Imagine reading your proof replacing "fail" and "close" by "A" and "B" and try to convince yourself of it soundnes then. Your first sentence then reads _"In the worst case scenario, Alex's first six attempts all give outcome A"_, but you don't show why that would be the worst case scenario.

Comment: Then, it is a matter of wording, not really related to the logic of the proof.

Comment: @Batominovski That is exactly my point, I believe your proof currently relies on the fallacy of assuming that getting an outcome named "fail" is automatically the worst one - a matter of wording. You actually have to prove that that is the worst case, and it's not possible to do worse by getting Close's.

Comment: This is an irrelevant point in my belief.  Whatever you are trying to say does not affect my argument, so I will not change the wording.

Comment: Your daily poor discussion. -1.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Is there anything you can contribute to this site today?  You are not too lazy to go through my stuff, but too lazy to learn about fields.

Comment: yeah I noticed poor user.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki  And **you** are the one to say that...  Hypocrisy is ripe.

Comment: I tell you that serial voting are too bad.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki If you are going to binge downvote me, make sure you actually got **bad answers**.  I actually downvoted your actual bad answers, and please delete them.  I downvoted because I was disappointed how you tried to teach me to give good answers, when you couldn't.  If you downvoted my good answers for no reason but revenge, you will land yourself in a trouble.

Comment: @Batominovski Sorry that gauss's question was activated by you.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki  What Gauss's question?  Again, you should downvote bad answers only.  While I disagree with you, I don't downvote you when you give reasonable answers.  And you should delete the answers I downvoted, because they are wrong.